# iframe float both top and right

Tags: html, css, iframe

I'm making a little html page to include in my sister's "presentation" (school). I've created a table which includes several rows and the first column has a link whose `target="ifr"`, the iframe. These links include an explanation of the element.

I want to include that iframe on the right side to make the page more fancy, but I'm getting troubles, trying to make the iframe floating both right and up.

iframe code:

```
    <iframe style="float:right;" width="575px" height="800px" id="ifr" name="ifr" src="no-src.html"></iframe>
```

table:

```
<table border=1 bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding=15 cellspacing=0>

<tr valign=top> <!-- category-->
    <td align="center">
        <FONT COLOR="#800000" FACE="TimesNewRomanPSMT, sans-serif" SIZE=3><B>Denominazione</B></FONT>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <FONT COLOR="#800000" FACE="TimesNewRomanPSMT, sans-serif" SIZE=3><B>Gene</B></FONT>
    </td>
    <td align="center">
        <FONT COLOR="#800000" FACE="TimesNewRomanPSMT, sans-serif" SIZE=3><B>Origine</B></FONT>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr valign=top> <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
    <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a></td>
    <td align="center">17q23</td>
    <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
</tr>
```

Here's what I get:[image: what i get]

And here's what i want:[image: what i want]

I thought to make them part of an `<ul>` and use `display:inline`, but I've got only some bases of html/css. Thanks in advance

Comment: It would be good for you to provide a fiddle :)

Comment: This is happening because you are working with a TABLE which has TR's (rows), and thus the elements stay in their row.. unless taken out of the flow.. (position:absolute|fixed?).. btw I think <font> tag has been deprecated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/wK2Rj/2/)**, also a fullscreen result [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/wK2Rj/2/embedded/result/)

Updated : removed non html5 `valign`

I suggest not to use `<font>` its quite old way, instead style by css.

html

```
<table border=1 bordercolor="#000000" cellpadding=15 cellspacing=0>
    <tr>
        <!-- category-->
        <td align="center">Denominazione</td>
        <td align="center">Gene</td>
        <td align="center">Origine</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <!-- first row, there are 12 of these-->
        <td><a href="pc.html" target="ifr">Paramiotonia congenita (PC)</a>
        </td>
        <td align="center">17q23</td>
        <td>Ereditarietà autosomica dominante</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<iframe style="float:right;" width="575px" height="800px" id="ifr" name="ifr" src="no-src.html"></iframe>
```

css

```
td {
    color:#800000;
    font-family:"TimesNewRomanPSMT, sans-serif";
    font-size: 14px;
}
tr {
    vertical-align: top; /* valign=top is not used now */
}
table {
    width: calc(100% - 580px); /* negate the width of iframe also borders */
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: fyi: the valign property is not supported in HTML5